# Download image in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I download image in laravel?

```
$file= "http://localhost/laravel/public/galleries/image.png";
$headers = array('Content-Type: image/png');
return Response::download($file, 'download_image.png',$headers);
```

I can't open this image.

Comment: So what kind of output did you get? Did you get any error?

Comment: Try the path like this `"http://localhost/laravel/galleries/image.png"`

Comment: If i tried to open downloaded image, it say corrupted image.

Comment: Then perhaps check if the image is actually corrupted, a wrong MIME type (although it is set as .png it might have been something else), or check file permission.

Comment: `$file` is supposed to be a local file ("C:/webserver/htdocs/laravel/public/...", not a HTTP resource). Open the file with notepad and show us the contents. It is most probably Debug output. You'll probably show us a "File not found" exception.

Comment: It probably has to do with how your development environment is setup.  Try using the code to read from an external website.  If you want to read a local image, then open/read it using fopen() or the like.

Answer (score 1):

The file needs to be referenced via the filesystem.

Windows Example : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\files\image.png

Then in your controller:

```
return Response::download('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\files\image.png');
```